# How to transpose array elements?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$categories` in php as follows.

```
Array
(
    [item_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => I-Phone
            [1] => samsung
            [2] => nokia
            [3] => htc
        )

    [item_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30.00
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 15
        )
)
```

And I want to transpose its element as,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => I-Phone
            [item_price] => 30.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => samsung
            [item_price] => 20
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => nokia
            [item_price] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => htc
            [item_price] => 15
        )
)
```

I've tried using foreach loop but not working.

```
$count=0;
foreach ($categories as $key=> $category)
{
        $categories[$count] = $category[$key];
        $categories[$count] = $category[$key];
        $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
$categories = array(
    'item_name' => array('I-Phone', 'samsung', 'nokia','htc'),
    'item_price' => array('30.00', '20', '10', '15')
);

$out = array();
foreach($categories as $key => $a){
    foreach($a as $k => $v){
        $out[$k][$key] = $v;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Sure, the outer foreach runs twice, once for item_name and once for item_price. On the first pass, it creates four new array items `$out[0]['item_name']` through `$out[3]['item_name']`. On the second pass, the item_prices are filled in. Note that if the two arrays must have the same number of elements. If they have different numbers of elements, this will not work as expected.

Comment: The explanation should inside the question.  Please edit your answer then delete the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using `array_keys` and `array_map` functions:

```
$keys = array_keys($categories);
$transposed = array_map(function($a, $b) use($keys){
    return [$keys[0] => $a, $keys[1] => $b];
}, $categories['item_name'], $categories['item_price']);

print_r($transposed);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => I-Phone
            [item_price] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => samsung
            [item_price] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => nokia
            [item_price] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => htc
            [item_price] => 15
        )    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$categories = array();  // your array
$ctg_names = array_keys($categories);   // get names of source array keys
$new_ctgs = array();   // result array

// iterate over first key values to get indexes
foreach ($categories[$ctg_names[0]] as $k => $v) {
    $ctg = array();
    // iterate over all key names
    foreach ($ctg_names as $name) {
        $ctg[$name] = $categories[$name][$k];
    }
    $new_ctgs[] = $ctg;
}

print_r($new_ctgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    'item_name' => Array
        (
            '0' => 'I-Phone',
            '1' => 'samsung',
            '2' => 'nokia',
            '3' => 'htc',
        ),

    'item_price' => Array
        (
            '0' => 30.00,
            '1' => 20,
            '2' => 10,
            '3' => 15,
        )
);

$keys = array_keys($array);
$result = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($array['item_name']); $i++)
{
    $tempArray = array();
    foreach($keys as $key)
        $tempArray[$key] = $array[$key][$i];

    $result[] = $tempArray;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => I-Phone
            [item_price] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => samsung
            [item_price] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => nokia
            [item_price] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_name] => htc
            [item_price] => 15
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = [];
foreach($categories['Item_name'] as $key => $data){
    $result[$key]['category'] = $categories['Item_name']['$key'];
    $result[$key]['price'] = $categories['price'][$key]; 
}
dd($result);
```

Comment: This is a low-value, code-only answer which will not provide the desired output due to a typographical error.